# Issue with mounting EFS access point from an AWS ECS Fargate task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, subnet

I am trying to launch fargate task from EFS . My EFS filesystem is mounted on Same subnet, VPC and security group where my ECS is mounted.

still I am facing the same issue  "*failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: Failed to resolve "fs-0b5a160420b31f547.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct, and ensure that the VPC has an EFS mount target for this file system ID"*

In my security group of ECS and EFS 2049 is enabled on inbound and Outbound network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution by my own I haven't done VPC DNS name enabled as it was set as disable i changed it to enabled and then ITWoRKS.